# Jenkins : Depends: net-tools but it is not installable - Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

While trying to run `sudo apt-get install jenkins` I am getting this issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After too much effort it worked. For that we need to check Software & Updates application.
later that we need to check 1st and 2nd tick mark should be.

[image]

If In case 2nd one is not true then try to run this command `sudo add-apt-repository universe`.
So that it will tick mark for 2nd one as well.

This worked for me.